# Getting ALL the actions for a given account using cleos

Tags: cleos, accounts, action

If I run:

```
$ cleos -u <api endpoint> -j --full <account>
```

I do not get all the actions. I don't know what the default range is. So I tried:

```
$ cleos -u <api endpoint> -j --full <account> 0 1000
```

Now I am getting all my actions as I have under 1000 so far. So far I don't see how I can always get all the actions for a given account without making up large number for the range. Any ideas?

Also, in another SO post I was adviced not to use the **inline_traces** keys to find my actions. But I do not see how I can find all the actions without recursively traversing the **inline_traces** key.

For example, I have a lot of actions like eos.names refunds and they are only available in **inline_traces** branch of the JSON data structure.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, I don't see a datestamp for each action the JSON feed returned by get_actions API call for an account. Should I assume the action timestamp to be the block_time?

Comment: What plugins do you have enabled on this machine?

Comment: The api endponit points to a node producer's system so does it matter what EOS plugins are turned on on the machine where I compiled the cleos. I basically cloned the eosio source and ran the build script to build cleos. So default plugins should be on but I am using a remote API endpoint since I haven't connected my eos node to mainnet, which is the next step in my EOSIO TODO list. :)

Comment: the default returns last 20 records

Comment: Yes, I know of that and I mentioned 0 1000 in my question. So the number of records is not the issue. What seems to the case with "get actions" is that it only reports the actions initiated by an account. When an account is OUTBID in an eos.names contract, the contract refunds the initial bid by the account. This is the action that is not accessible by the "get actions" on a given account.

Comment: The workarounds I have implemented is to get all the "bid" actions that are done by an account and then I queried the system bidnameinfo <bidname> to see if the account is still the highest bidder or not. If not, I can assume refund action. :)